# Xcode 3.2.1 Cant Find iPhone Section, when creating a new project.?

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-developer-program

I recently downgraded to Xcode 3.2.1 to learn from the new boston tutorial. When launching Xcode, there popup saying new project. Then after that, when you chose selection if you to build a Mac app or iphone app, there isnt a iPHONE section? just a mac os selection.

Comment: Don't punish yourself. Try to find tutorials about developing for iOS 6. There is absolutely no reason to learn developing on iOS4 with Xcode 3.2.1. So many changes happened between iOS 4 and 6, you will waste a lot of time if you start with those ancient tutorials. Once you have mastered Xcode 3.2.1 you have to master Xcode 4; otherwise you won't be able to submit an app. Once you learned about how stuff worked on iOS 4 you switch to iOS 6 and you can replace 500 line iOS4 Classes with 5 lines of UIAppearance etc. It's not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

That means the iOS SDK is not installed. You need to dig through the developer site to find the right iOS SDK to install as well. If that doesn't fix it you will have to make the translations from Xcode 3 to 4 in order to follow the tutorial (maybe find a tutorial focused on Xcode 4 to find where things are in it).